# Could someone translate these verses from Brahma Vaivarta Puranam, please?

Tags: translation-request, cows, brahma-vaivarta-purana

Do these verses mention about cow slaughter?

Please translate it completely.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There is mention of the slaughter of various animals including the cow for a banquet. The following translation omits translating the line with cows in it but the word "gavAM" is very clearly present (first half of verse 61).

Some things to keep in mind when reading this:

- This happened in Dvapara yuga.
- The Purana is a less-reliable source due to being one of the Rajasic group as categorized by the Padma Purana.
- The speaker urging the slaughter of cows is Rukmi, the brother of Rukmini. He is described in this very same Purana to be a person associated with Adharma. Eventually he was defeated by Krishna but spared to live.

BTW, there are typos in this translation. 'Rubies' should be 'Rabbits', etc.

[image]

Here's a translation of verse 61:

> gavāṃ lakṣam chedanaṃ ca hariṇānām dvilakṣakam। caturlakṣaṃ śaśanāṃ ca
> kūrmāṇām ca tathā kuru॥
>
> Slaughter one lakh cows, two lakh deer, four lakh rabbits and the same
> number of tortoises.

Comment: Can u pls specify which chapter is this?

Comment: @YDS - It's Krishna janma kanda - chapter 105 -https://archive.org/details/brahma-vaivarta-purana-all-four-kandas-english-translation/page/652/mode/2up

Comment: @hash - You can add the link  provided in above comment in your answer instead of screenshot.

Comment: "The following translation omits translating the line with cows in it" - lol

Comment: Agreed. Which is why I requested for the correct translation. I am just learning to read Sanskrit.

Comment: @strugglingseeker Added translation for that verse.

Comment: I'm sure you realize these verses provide fodder to the beef-mafia. Every non Kali-Yuga-sanctioned practice must be mentioned with that context - that this was done in previous Yugas, when people of higher spirituality could differentiate yagna meat from McDonalds meat. The Purana must also be attested with the Rajasic category. The speaker of this conversation (and thus his bad-nature) must also be mentioned - one who advises king Rukmi against selecting Krishna as the groom.

Comment: @ram updated as suggested.

Comment: Here's how this "jugglery" works. If it's not conducive with our current beliefs about a particular practice, just assign spiritual downfall to the current age people or say the practice is banned in this yuga. If that does not work, plead to ignore the verse as hyperbole. **Furthermore**, as discussed Excellently in [this awesome QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9975/what-is-the-purpose-of-tamasic-purana-if-it-leads-to-hell) - There's is absolutely no basis, whatsoever to the propagated Nonsense concept of the "Sattvic-Rajasic-Tamasic" classification of texts.