# Is Vishnu called internally or externally Tamasic in Suta Gita and Shiva Dharmottara Purana?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, puranas, translation-request, reference-request

As you may know, Shiv Purana says Vishnu Bhagavan and Laxmi Mata are only externally Saatvik looking but their true nature is Taamsik ([Here](https://archive.org/details/SivaPuranaJ.L.ShastriPart1/page/n257/)). Skand Puran also says Vaishnav Puranas are Taamsik and shouldn't be read by Brahmins ([Here](https://archive.org/details/SriSkandaPuranam-SankaraSamhitaPart2/page/n9/mode/2up)).

Here's one more:

> **Soot Gita (2.40-41):** asti rudrasya viprendrA antaH sattvaM bahistamaH | *viShNorantastamaH sattvaM bahirasti* rajoguNaH || antarbahishcha viprendrA asti tasya prajApateH ([Original with Sanskrit explanation](https://archive.org/details/SutaSamhita-volume2/page/n409/mode/2up?view=theater))

This definitely seems to say that Vishnu has a tamasic body. As per [Smriti sect/Shankaracharya following website](https://www.advaita-vedanta.org/archives/advaita-l/2019-January/051297.html), there is another confirmation in Shiva Dharmottara Purana.

> **Shiv Dharmottar Puran (unknown):** antah sattvagunopeto bahistaamasasamyutah shuddha saattvika ityuktah shankaro lokashankarah antastaamasa shamyuktto bahih sattvagunaanvitah shuddha *taamasa ityukto vishnussaakshaat* sriyah patih

Can somebody please fully translate both these sentences and also find exact references/links for the second one?

Comment: of the 18 puranas, 6 are satvik, 6 are rajasik and 6 are tamasik. Shiva Puran & Skand Puran fall under Tamasik puranas. The nature of Tamas is destruction, and Shiva is the deva responsible for controlling this guna, so he channels it to destroy worlds.

Comment: According to Mahabharata all 18 puranas are sattvik and leads to moksha. Even padma puran says the same and thus contradicting its own verses. Skanda puran says all vaishnava purans are tamsik n shiva Puranas are sattvik and brahma's rajasik. So, these are all sectatorian interpolations from all the sects and nothing else. And according to lord Krishna in Mahabharata and vedas, lord Shiva is above all gunas. According to Shiv Puran Lord Vishnu is sattvik from outside (duties) and tamsik from inside whereas Lord Rudra is Tamsik from outside and Sattvik from inside. And so on.

Comment: .️☮️.

Comment: @mar as per Shaivism scriptures Vishnu and his puranas are Tamsic... Shiv-Shakti followers are satvic because we don't differentiate between vegetables, meat or urine. Only a tamasic god and his followers make distinctions between things. Shivji's job only is Tamasic but he is PURE SATVIK and perfect incarnation internally..... unlike Vishnu who's body is PURE TAMASIC and Vishnu is a defective incarnation

Comment: @Savdy Actually Vaishnav purans accept they are defective and Srimad Bhagvat is better than them. MBH is a Vaishnava itihasa so I wouldn't give it much importance. Krishna makes several mistakes like when he says Vishwaroop is being shown for first time.... but MBH itself says Lord Ram showed his Vishwaroop...... more proof that Vishnu is Tamasic

Comment: @R. Kaushik i believe all 18 Puranas are above 3 gunas or otherwise vedavyasa would be damned to hell. Plus puranas were actually a single book divided into 18 for simplifying it. And As for Mahabharata its not a vaishnava or shaiva or any sectatorian itihasa. Yes it most describes the 8th avatar of Lord Vishnu viz Lord Krishna but in many places Lord Shiva is considered Supreme. Plus Shankara=Narayana concept is also there. And I think Tridevs are equal and they can change their gunas according to their work and will. All 3 of them are a part of Parambrahma divided into 3.

Answer (score 1):

I am just translating here.:

> *Soot Gita (2.40-41).: asti rudrasya viprendrA antaH sattvaM bahistamaH | viShNorantastamaH sattvaM bahirasti || rajoguNaH antarbahishcha viprendrA asti tasya prajApateH |*
>
> *Rudra the Lord of the Brahmanas is of Sattvika nature from internally and Tamasik nature from externally.*
>
> *Vishnu is of Tamasik nature from internally and Sattvik nature from externally.*
>
> *Prajapati (Brahmā) is of Rajasik nature from both internally and externally.*

And.,

> *Shiv Dharmottar Purana.: antah sattvagunopeto bahistaamasasamyutah shuddha saattvika ityuktah shankaro lokashankarah । antastaamasa shamyuktto bahih sattvagunaanvitah shuddha taamasa ityukto vishnussaakshaat sriyah patih ।।*
>
> *Lord Shankara is endowed with Sattva guna internally and Tamasik guna externally. So, the Lord of the World (Shankara) is purely Sattvik in nature.*
>
> *Lord Vishnu is endowed with Tamasik guna internally and Sattvik guna externally. So, The Husband of the Sri (Vishnu) is purely Tamasik in nature.*

Hope it helps.