# What does the gunas of puranas signify?

Tags: puranas, gunas, interpretation

There are 18 maha puranas in Sanathan Dharma. They can be classified based on their gunas. The [following](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35477/661) is the [classification](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11329/661) with some caveats

> Bhagavata, Vishnu, Garuda, Matsya, Kurma and Vayu are Satvika Puranas.
>
> Skanda, Padma, Varaha, Vamana, Agni and Bhavishya are Rajasa Puranas
>
> Brahma, Brahmananda, Brahmavaivarta, Linga, Markandeya and Aditya are Tamasa Puranas.

In this context, I have the following doubt(s)

Do we need to interpret the statements in those Puranas based on their corresponding gunas? or does it depend on the ishta diety also? or do gunas tell us about the knowledge level required by the reader to interpret them?

Comment: Please try to comment the reason for down-vote if possible.

Comment: @SK Please provide a link. I heard from authentic preachings also.

Comment: @SK You can check [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11329/661).

Comment: @SK What is the other purana?

Comment: @SK If you observe, both the Puranas you mentioned are Rajas. I think we need more knowledge about gunas of puranas to understand the statements.

Comment: @SK The linked answer contains the answer to your concern. That's why I wrote, "with some caveats".

Comment: I'm done with this thread.

Comment: @hanugm The classification you've given is not the only classification found in scriptures. You can find a different one here -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/46389/4732

Comment: First of all gunas based classification is found in Shaiva perspective also [Skanda Purana, Samhita Version](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46387/which-4-vishnu-vaishnava-puranas-are-called-tamasic-and-not-meant-for-brahmins/46389#46389). Secondly, this triguna classification is not unique to Vaisnavas- Shiva Purana Verse 2.1.16.37-40 does say, Vishnu is internally Tamsika, while Rudra is internally Sattvika.  So, these classifications sounds more like sectarian interpolations rather than anything to do with "knowledge-level". P.S. I didn't Downvote.

Comment: @Rickross Oh... I will then need to edit it asap... Thanks...

Comment: @Vivikta Oh thanks... will read.

Comment: the classification is for people of that gunas. for e.g. people with rajasik guna are the right audience for rajasa puranas, because they are full of description of passionate acts. @Vivikta - "Sectarian interpolation" is different from "sectarian interpretation". Also, if two people say "I alone am correct" - it doesn't mean both are equal. it just means that either both are wrong, or only one of them is correct. just because two people say "i am the king", both of them should be disregarded ? No. only one of them is correct.